# Ocultar Row GridView C# / ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, gridview

Numa `GridView` de utilizadores, se o próprio utilizador clicar em editar/apagar a sua própria conta, gostaria de saber como ocultar a row ou desativar o botão da `GridView` mas apenas para o utilizador logado, ou se clicar no botão para editar/apagar dar erro de modo a prevenir que o próprio seja apagado/editado.

Tentei algo assim:

```
            if (IDUtilizador == Convert.ToInt32(Session["IDUtilizador"]))
            {
                lblUtilizadoresInfo.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblUtilizadoresInfo.Text = "Operação mal sucedida, para alterar as definições de newsletter, acesse Front Office, 'Minha Conta', 'Assinaturas'.";
                lblUtilizadoresInfo.Visible = true;
                MultiViewContentInfo.Visible = true;
                GridViewManage.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Mas dessa maneira sempre que clico no botão voltar do browser consigo editar esse utilizador, sendo um enorme bug.

Obrigado.

Comment: Já foi resolvido, era um erro entre sessions do IDUtilizador.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta algo assim:

```
 if (IDUtilizador == Convert.ToInt32(Session["IDUtilizador"]))
        {
            btn_EditarApagar.Enabled = false
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nessa situação irá desactivar o button para todos os utilizadores?

Comment: Sim, realmente fica, coloca um else...